# How do I screen-capture an inactive window?

Tags: wine

How can I screen-capture an inactive (minimized / on another workspace) window in Ubuntu?

Applications like ImageMagick's import are only able to capture active windows. When attempting to capture an inactive window, I get the following message:

```
unable to read X window image `<id>': Resource temporarily unavailable @ error/xwindow.c/XImportImage/5023.
```

Might be able to do this using Compiz, as it is able to render previews of inactive windows. Furthermore, in my specific case, the window I want to capture is run in a *Wine Explorer*-container. Inside that container the application is always active.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something similar with `shutter`.

However, it doesn't appear to be exactly what you're looking for (sadly), but it's the closest I could find.

1. Install [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/). Run `sudo apt-get install shutter` in your terminal.
2. Select the applet in your menubar like shown below. [image: Screenshot of]
3. Now, you can select the window that you want to have the screenshot taken of, and click on it's menu item.
4. Now, Shutter will bring that window to the focus and take a screenshot.